# Como crear el Bundle para publicar en Google Play, app hecha en Flutter con Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

Tengo una app desarrollada en Flutter y Android Studio, ya lista para publicar en Google Play.
Al intentar crear el bundle en build----> flutter----> Bundle muestra el error siguiente.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file 'C:\Users\ADMIN\FlutterProyects2023\farmacodosis\android\settings.gradle line: 3
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.

> Could not find method File() for arguments [C:\Users\ADMIN\FlutterProyects2023\farmacodosis\android, local.properties] on settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

He seguido todos los pasos de la documentacion de Flutter, he buscado respuestas en Stackoverflow  y no he tenido el resultado que espero.
Quedo pendiente de sus respuestas.

Comment: Al parecer en vez de `flutter build apk` es `flutter build appbundle`. https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle

Comment: Que contiene tu archivo settings.gradle y local.properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Tu archivo `settings.gradle`, debe tener la definición de tu archivo `local.properties`, revisa que contenga:

```
def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()
```